# File uploads in Django: prevent FileField from writing the full path to the database

Tags: django

I'm building a software repository on top of the Django framework. Because it will contain a lot of files, i want it to make some sense when looking at it through a file manager. So i grouped the files first by the URL of a program they belong to and then by first two letters of that URL. Here's how it looks:

[image: screenshot of my directory structure]

The schema looks like this:

```
class File(models.Model):
    # If called like upload_to, don't put a slash in front of the result
    # because we already have one in settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    def get_absolute_url(self, filename=None):
        return '%sfiles/%s/%s/%s' % ('' if filename else '/',
                                     self.download.url[:2],
                                     self.download.url,
                                     filename or self.name)
    name = models.FileField(upload_to=get_absolute_url, max_length=255)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    download = models.ForeignKey('Download', related_name='files')


class Download(models.Model):
    url = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

There is, however, a minor problem: FileField will store the entire generated path instead of just the name, which i would rather like to avoid. Is there any way to override (probably in my own field class) what FileField writes to the database and how it reconstructs the path after loading the raw field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name = models.FileField(upload_to=get_absolute_url, max_length=255)
```

upload_to usually looks like this

```
upload_to ='./files'
```

It will be stored as ./files/your.file in the db
and as `<MEDIA_ROOT>/files/your.file` at your disk

You can change the `upload_to`-String to whatever fits best for you programatically

```
upload_to ='./files'+'/subdir'
```

but it should start with './'

[FileField-Reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)

`get_absolute_url()` should return a url like http://domain.com/sitemedia/files/your.file

**EDIT:**

to remove the path from the file name you could do string operations in File.save() like

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.name = self.name[self.name.rfind('/')+1:]
    super(File, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```